# created_at/updated_at is null when seading file

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel and I have created the following seeder:

```
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
        $limit = 20;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
            DB::table('data_sources')->insert([
                'name' => $faker->name(),
                'description' => $faker->sentence(),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

My migration file looks like the following:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('data_sources', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('google_sheets_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('google_sheets_id')->references('id')->on('google_sheets')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

When running the seeder only `name` and `description` gets updated.

Any suggestions why `timestamps()` do not get updated?

Appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes will be set automatically if you use [Eloquent model](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent). if you don't have a model for your `data_sources` table, you can create one:

```
php artisan make:model DataSource
```

Then use it to insert a new record:

```php
$dataSource = new DataSource;
$dataSource->name = $faker->name();
$dataSource->description = $faker->sentence();
$dataSource->save();
```

Or using `create` method:

```php
App\DataSource::create([
    'name' => $faker->name(),
    'description' => $faker->sentence(),
]);
```

Note: the `create` method protects the model against [mass-assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) by default, so don't forget to define `$fillable` property on the model:

```php
protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes will be set automatically if you use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) model.

But you are using Raw SQL Queries. In this case, you need to insert the data manually as following.

On top of the class

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
```

And modify your run method with created_at, updated_at

```
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $limit = 20;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
        DB::table('data_sources')->insert([
            'name' => $faker->name(),
            'description' => $faker->sentence(),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your seeder

```
'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Don't forget to import `Carbon` class